# Search for String in List

Tags: java, list

```
public Account findByInterest(String interest){
    for(Map.Entry<Long, Account> e : accounts.entrySet()){
        for(int i = 0; i < e.getValue().getInterests().size(); i++)
        {
            if(e.getValue().getInterests().get(i) == interest){
                return e.getValue();
            }
        }

    }
    return null;
}
```

I'm trying to search in a `HashTable` of Objects to find an objected with a List of Strings, which has the same string as this method receives... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

To compare string values use the [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

Change

```
if(e.getValue().getInterests().get(i) == interest){
```

to

```
if(e.getValue().getInterests().get(i).equals(interest)){
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doen't help. Still receive NullPointerException..

Comment: Then you should check for null before you call the methods.

Comment: Why is this the first time that `NullPointerException` is mentioned?  1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Always copy/paste error & exception output.